# I need to solve this probally bug with returning function

Tags: java, android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

[code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7pTgp.png)

when i debug it, the return runs first, then the mCode = document.get("code").toString() runs ;-;

mCode is a lateinit var, so when it returns, mCode isnt initialized

Comment: Hello, please post codes as text not screen shots .. this allows a one that can offer help to test and also pics don't remain long on web, so the quest may be distorted in the future

Comment: I tried it, but the code wasnt idented like it expected

Comment: In that case, read https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90407/easy-way-to-indent-code, https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks, https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/207842/how-to-easily-indent-multi-line-code, or https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125148/implement-style-fenced-markdown-code-blocks.

Answer (score 0):

It is because the `.addOnSuccessListener()` and `.addOnFailureListener()` are asynchronous methods, so they will be executed just when receive the result from the call.

What you can do is like:

```
...
    .get().addOnSuccessListener(...{
        override fun onSucess(document: DocumentSnapshot) {
            onSuccessAction(document)
        }
    })
...

private fun onSuccessAction(document: DocumentSnapshot) {
    mCode = document.get("code").toString()
    if (code == mCode) {
        // Do anything...
    }
}
```

Comment: Vi que tu é br kskskss, mano, não foi ;-;

Comment: Esse retorno seria pra view model, a função está no repository. Vou usar um mutable live data do repositório pra viewmodel. quando a variável atualizar, ele vai informar.